# is it possible to create two deployments inside one namespace in K8S?

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kustomize, skaffold

I am begginer at K8S, i'm using github actions
I have 3 environment (dev, pred-prod, prod) and 3 namespace to each environment, i want to have a second environment (pre-prod-2) into my namespace of pre-production; is it possible ?
and how the yaml file will look like ?

Thank you

Comment: its possible...

Comment: Short answer, yes it is...just give them different labels and names and you are done 

Comment: @hackerman, when you say labels and names, you mean in the deployment.yml file or ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create another independent deployment in the same namespace, take your existing Deployment YAML and change the following fields:

- metadata.name
- spec.selector.matchLabels.app
- template.metadata.labels.app

It will be sufficient to just append a "2" to each of these values.